# delete cascade laravel not working

Tags: php, laravel

I have a problem with delete  using laravel 5.4

I have 3 tables: Users, Posts, Vechicles

User hasMany Posts

Vehicle belognsTo Post

Post hasMany Vehicles

...anyway...when creating the schema for the vehicle table, i use 2 foreign keys:

```
$table->foreign('post_id')->references('id')->on('posts')->onDelete('cascade');
$table->foreign('post_user_id')->references('user_id')->on('posts');
```

When i want to delete a post, all the vehicles that are related to the post to be deleted....but is not working (it gives an error about constraint)

Can someone tell me what i am wrong? it is that i am using 2 foregin keys?

Comment: What is the error for the constraint?

Comment: Please add schema diagram for your relationships between table. Your description is quit unclear

Comment: @RuChernChong When i want to delete a post the error is:QLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails. CONSTRAINT `vehicles_post_user_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`post_user_id`) REFERENCES `posts` (`user_id`). 
SagarGautam here is the schema [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qdsjwkq4tas5jn2/diagram.png?dl=0)

I think is beacuse of the foreign key post_user_id which is also pointing at the post table.

Answer (score 0):

check this

```
$table->engine = "InnoDB";
```

Comment: it is using InnoDB...i use mysql btw. I was trying: to delete the vehicles..then delete the post in the destory function. lic function 
   `$post = Post::find($id);     $post->vehicles()->where('post_id', $id)->delete();  $post->delete(); return redirect()->route('home'); `

Comment: BTW no need for where('post_id', $id) already you get the post by find

Answer (score 0):

Using one foreign key solve the issue:

```
 Schema::create('vehicles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('mark');
        $table->string('model');
        $table->integer('weight');
        $table->string('vehicle_state');
        $table->integer('post_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('post_user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('post_id')->references('id')->on('posts')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
```